# CSS a.active not working

Tags: html, css

I have a Navigationbar at the top of my Page and the active Page should have another background color. I have the color and red right now, so its obvious to see. But no red on the Page.

My HTML:

```
<body>

<ul>
  <li class="<?= ($activePage == 'index') ? 'active':''; ?>"><a href="index.php">Login</a></li>
  <li class="<?= ($activePage == 'Login') ? 'active':''; ?>"><a href="Login.php">Profil</a></li>
  <li class="<?= ($activePage == 'Profilchange') ? 'active':''; ?>"><a href="Profilchange.php">Profil bearbeiten</a></li>
  <li class="<?= ($activePage == $Profilkennungbasename) ? 'active':''; ?>"><a href='http://localhost/PHPOrdner/Login/<?php echo $Profilerow; ?>'>öffentliches Profil</a></li>
  <li style="float:right;" class="<?= ($activePage == 'Logout') ? 'active':''; ?>"><a style="background-color:#002b80" href="Logout.php">Ausloggen</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
```

My CSS:

```
    <style>

  body {
    font-family: "Arial", Sans-serif;
  }

  input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #000099;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    width: 13.5%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #000066;
  }

  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000099;
  }

  li {
    float: left;
  }

  li:last-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  }

  li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  }

  li a:hover {
    background-color: #000066;
  }

  li a.active {
    background-color: #FF0000;
  }

  a:link, a:visited {
    background-color: #000099;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:200px;
  }

  a:hover {
    background-color: #000066;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

</style>
```

I am still very new to HTML, CSS and PHP, so i guess it's obvious. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding `active` class on the `li` element and not on the `a` so the selector should be

```
li.active a {
  /* styles goes here */
}
```

In the above selector, I select the `li` element having a `class` of `active` and then we select the `a` nested inside this `li`

---

One more thing I see in your code is that you are using inline styles like `style="background-color:#002b80"`, so if you are going to use inline styles, they will override your CSS rule declarations as inline styles are most specific.

You either need to override them using `!important` or you need to move them to a `class` and append the `class` to the respective element.

So avoid using inline styles.

[Read more on the specificity here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)